# Automatically ban IPs that request certain pages

Tags: iptables, nginx, aws

I want to ban IPs that request certain pages e. g. `example.com/weird.php` and one that send a `POST` request to `example.com/weirder.php`.

I have searched a lot, and learned about several `iptables`, but seems some are instructions for CentOS.  I also worry about being locked out. So I'm looking for somewhat detailed and safe answer.

I use AWS EC2, Ubuntu and nginx.

Comment: Link to the instructions you are talking about?  (Note there's no way to do this within nginx)

Comment: Not sure what link I was talking about in the question. but I searched again and saw this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576040/block-ip-addresses-that-request-a-specific-url   I assume this should work independent of nginx and apache. right?

Answer (score 2):

First try this on a machine you have physical access to.

## IP Tables

First, let's figure out the IP Tables rules to block an IP Address. For detailed instructions, [check out this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-block-an-ip-on-my-linux-server/).Let's drop all incoming connections from a particular IP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s A.B.C.D -j DROP
```

After this, restart iptables as regular. Try out this command to check if it works fine for you, get familiar with the syntax and then proceed further.

## Bash Script

Let's create a Bash Script to block an IP. It would look something like this (warning: You might need to play with user permissions and sudo to get it to work). Create a new file, say, blockip.sh.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
iptables -A INPUT -s $1 -d DROP
<other stuff you want to do when you block an IP>
<note: the IP address is in variable $1>
```

Run `chmod +x blockip.sh` to make the script executable. Now you can run it as `/path/to/file/blockip.sh 1.2.3.4`.

## Sudo Permissions

If your script needs to have root user permissions, you need to configure sudo to provide you passwordless access. Referring from [this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915241/how-to-run-from-php-a-bash-script-under-root-user.), run `sudo visudo` and add the following line:

```
nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /your/script
```

Save the file and exit. As a security warning, make sure that only you can modify the script file or else, someone can potentially run harmful code as root user by modifying the script.

## PHP Code

Run this little gem of code whenever you want to block someone.

```
exec("sudo /path/to/file/blockip.sh ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

## Conclusion

First, test this code on a machine you have physical access to. Also, be aware that multiple users behind a LAN would share the same external IP and blocking one of them would result in blocking all of them. Be careful. Upvote if the answer helped you.

Comment: Maybe this is what I will do. thanks. although I wanted to do it through an automatic rule from a webserver or iptables by checking the request without need for php. but maybe this is the easiest.  The ones I want to ban are infected machines sent by spammers to a page that is non-existent. they are mostly zombie machines with malicious code.

Comment: Basically, if the script is successfully made, you can figure out some other method to run it as well.

Comment: Also, if you find out that it works, mark my answer as the accepted answer. You're welcome.

Comment: but I'm looking for a way to do it without php. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Your question points to php with all fingers. Literally, "that request certain pages e.g. example.com/weird.php"..... So, it makes sense to put any blocking code in php as well. But if you so want, as I said above, you can execute that script with another netstat based bash script.